# ssh command not found in terminal

Tags: ssh, terminal, osx

I appear to have messed up my terminal (on an OSX if that matters) big time. When I try to `SSH` I get `-bash: ssh: command not found`

After working with the command suggested to me of `declare -p PATH` I get `declare -x PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:‌​"`

Now I'm lost as to what I did and how to fix it. I'm not very knowledgeable in this area and super frustrated that I clearly dabbled in something I should have left alone.

(Edit, forgot to bring over some other content)
When I run `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO+' bash -x -l -i`, The resulting output containing `~/.bash_profile` is:

```
/Users/Name/.bash_profile:1+export PATH= /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin‌​:/opt/X11/bin} 
:/Users/Name/.bash_profile:1+PATH= bash: export: ``/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sb‌​in:/opt/X11/bin': not a valid identifier 
:/Users/Name/.bash_profile:5+PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python‌​.framework/Versions/‌​3.6/bin: :/Users/Name/.bash_profile:6+export PATH'
```

Comment: If you open a new terminal, is it still broken?

Comment: if opening a new terminal window doesn't fix it, try running ssh with the full path (since maybe you messed your path up).  type it like this and hit enter: `/usr/bin/ssh`

Comment: No, the new terminal didn't work. When I used `/usr/bin/ssh` I got `usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
       [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
           [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.bash_profile` appears to contain:

```
export PATH= /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin‌​:/opt/X11/bin}
```

This has two problems:

- The space after the `=` and before the value causes the value to be a separate argument to `export`, *not* part of the new value of `PATH`. Thus, what `export` sees is `PATH=` (setting the PATH to an empty string), and `/usr/local/sbin:...` (which isn't an assignment at all, and is thus ignored).
- The closing `}` is surely not desired.

Thus, you should modify the file to instead contain:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin‌​:/opt/X11/bin
```

...or, more simply:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin‌​:/opt/X11/bin
```

...as export is not needed here: Because PATH is already in the environment, updates are always exported automatically.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. Not sure how the space got in there. I tested it out and everything seems in working order!

Answer (score 4):

The default PATH on macOS is

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

If you run that in your terminal, you'll be back to normal.

If you've modified your `.bashrc` file, or similar, to add or change a line like that, remove it, or change it to

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:‌​$PATH"
```

Note in particular that **there is not a space after `PATH=`**; it’s all run together, and if you’ve made a change yours should be structured the same way. If you didn't, you can also just reopen your terminal and everything will be fine.

Comment: From prior discussion with this user on a [StackOverflow iteration of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103099/chmod-command-not-found), I believe they're updating their path in `.bash_profile`. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get them to edit the relevant content into the question, vs posting it in a comment, so the details are a bit hard to follow; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48103099/chmod-command-not-found#comment83690474_48103099

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added the output above. Let me know if there was something else I needed to add.

Comment: @walkingbytrees You need to take the space out after `PATH=`.